# Recurrence Relation involving Fractional Part

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fractional-part

I am considering the following sequence:
$$a_0=\sqrt 2$$
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\{a_n\}$$
where $\{x\}:= x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the fractional part function.
Since I have observed that the sequence exhibits almost-linear growth, I am trying to find the value of the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$$
This is by no means rigorous, but I believe that the value is $1/2$, because the $\{a_n\}$ seems to behave somewhat like a random variable, and if we instead considered the sequence
$$b_{n+1}=b_n+X_n$$
where each $X_n$ is a random variable uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$, the expected value of $\Delta b_n=X_n$ is $1/2$.

Any ideas about how to prove this more rigorously? Is my reasoning even correct?

Comment: Hi, so sorry but what does $\{a_n\}$ means in this context?

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Oh, sorry, I should have clarified. It denotes the fractional part of $a_n$:
$$\{a_n\}:= a_n-\lfloor a_n\rfloor $$

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat rigorous...

Let $\lfloor a_n \rfloor = I_n$, $\{a_n\} = f_n$.The problem can be decomposed into 
\begin{align}
f_{n+1} &= 2f_n - \mathbb{1}_{f_n \geq \frac{1}{2}} \\
I_{n+1} &= I_n + \mathbb{1}_{f_n \geq \frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}
The fractional part follows a [Bernoulli map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation), whose invariant density is the [uniform distribution](https://wiki.helsinki.fi/download/attachments/48862734/lecture_05.pdf) if $f_0$ is irrational, so that $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{f_k \geq \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
Therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{I_n}{n} =\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{f_k \geq \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Why is it only "somewhat" rigorous?